# How create new hive table from two existing ones having same columns

Tags: hive

I have two hive table :

```
> T1exp

Col1 Col2 Col3
1     5    7
3     4    6
4     2    1
```

and the table

```
> T2exp

Col1 Col2 Col3
0     5    4
1     2    2
4     3    1
```

I need to get one by merging both :

```
>FinalTable
Col1 Col2 Col3
1     5    7
3     4    6
4     2    1
0     5    4
1     2    2
4     3    1
```

I tried using this instruction :

```
 create TableRDH as (select * from T2exp as t1 left.join FinalTable as t2 on t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 );
```

But it gives this error

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:7 cannot recognize input near 'create'
>   'TableRDH' 'as' in ddl statement

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to achieve your objective:

```
create table as 
select * from <T2exp>
union
select * from <FinalTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need do union to merge the table data,

Try,

```
create table as 
select col1, col2, col3 from <table1>
union
select col1, col2, col3 from <table2>
```

Note - Error which you are getting is due to syntax issue, try the query without keyword as and paranthesis